# FindwindowEx googlechrome WinAPI C#

Tags: c#, winapi, findwindow, findwindowex

I trying to look for the file opened in Google Chrome that found in the Taskbar
in the function FindWindowEx.
And that's what I made,help me to fixed the mistakes cause I dont understand how to do it.

```
    bool show = true;
    const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    const int SW_SHOW = 5;

    taskbarWnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);
    chromeWnd = FindWindowEx(taskbarWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Google Chrome", null);

    ShowWindow(chromeWnd, show ? SW_HIDE : SW_SHOW);
    show = !show
```

thanks for helping :)

Comment: Why do you think `Google Chrome` is the `class name` of the window you want to show? I highly recommend you to try `EnumChildWindows` and `GetClassName` to print all the `class names` of all the child windows.

Comment: If you want to know what file is open in Google Chrome, you need to find a Google Chrome API. Groveling into the taskbar accomplishes nothing. The taskbar doesn't know either.

Answer (score 0):

It used to work with:

```
FindWindowEx(hChrome, IntPtr.Zero, "Chrome_OmniboxView", IntPtr.Zero);
```

But I don't know if it's working anymore.